# Rails Rspec test fails: Failure/Error: FATAL: database "jmschp" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a project with `Rails 5.2.4.5`. Where I am using `Rspec` for testing, and Postgres as database.

```
RSpec 3.10
  - rspec-core 3.10.1
  - rspec-expectations 3.10.1
  - rspec-mocks 3.10.2
  - rspec-support 3.10.2
```

When I run `rails spec:helpers` I am getting the following error:

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/helpers/pluralize_without_count_helper_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError:
  FATAL:  database "jmschp" does not exist
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/helpers/pluralize_without_count_helper_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
# ------------------
# --- Caused by: ---
# PG::ConnectionBad:
#   FATAL:  database "jmschp" does not exist
#   ./spec/rails_helper.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.
```

I have droped the data base and recreated it again.

In my `database.yml` I have:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 6 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
  database: store_development

test:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV['TEST_DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

In development work fine.
How can I fix this?

Comment: I opened `psql` and created an empty database with the name. Seems like that resolved the issue. The test suite dropped the database and created it again. _(Note: Your mileage may vary.)_

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the name of the test database setup in database.yml you can try below

```
test:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['TEST_DATABASE_URL'] || 'store_development_test' %>
```

and run this to make sure test database has all the migrations applied.

```
bin/rails db:test:prepare
```

Comment: In my `.env` file my `TEST_DATABASE_URL` was set to `TEST_DATABASE_URL="postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres/store_test"`.
Because I installed `Postgres` using `Homebrew`, the deffault user role for the database is my user `jmschp` in my case. I changed the url to `TEST_DATABASE_URL="postgres://jmschp:postgres@localhost/store_test"`, and now it works. Thank you!